# Returning result from the first clicked Jbutton from multiple JButtons java swing

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Basically I have n JButtons. If any of them is clicked, they return a certain number. 
I have a menu with each of the buttons and when the user clicks one, my menu method returns the number returned by the Button handler. Is it possible?

Something like:

```
frame.add(button1..)
frame.add(button2..)
frame.add(button3..)
if (button1.isClicked()) {
    return button1ActionHandler();
} else if (button2.isClicked()) {
       return button2ActionHandler();
} else if (button3.isClicked()) {
             return button3ActionHandler();
}
```

The problem is, the code is not waiting for me to click a button so it won't enter in any of those if's. What can I do for the program to wait for click and how can I check if a button is clicked?

Comment: Clarify just what you mean by "menu with each of the buttons" -- that isn't clear to me at all. Otherwise your problem is that you're trying to use linear console type programming in an *event-driven* programming environment.

Comment: Menu with each of the buttons is basically... creating a frame and adding buttons to it. You are definitely right. I'm new to even driver programming and I come from console programming and I find it very hard to imagine how it works.

Comment: @Melye77 Event driven programming is actually relatively simple, but you need to trust in the system a little, for example, you need to trust then when a button (that you've registered a `ActionListener` to) will call your `ActionListener` when it's activated in some way (clicked and by the keyboard)

Comment: I do trust it though I want to use it in a different manner. I just care if it's clicked, because I need some results parsed around from function to function. My user has to make an important choice and that specific choice is telling me a lot of information. My actionListener doesn't have to do much actually :/ just to be there. I tried putting it all in a while that waits till a button is clicked but that just sets my code in an infinite loop. I'm lost

Answer (score 2):

Start by having a look at [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html).

Remember, a GUI is an event driven environment, that is, something and then you respond to it.

You need to register an `ActionListener` against each button, when the button is triggered, you need to take appropriate action.

There are a number of ways you could achieve this, you could set the `actionCommand` of the buttons with appropriate information that you can use to ascertain what should be done when the button is clicked.  You could use the `source` property of the `ActionEvent` to determine the source of the event and take appropriate action, as exampels

Comment: I need my menu to return whatever the first button clicked is returning. I can't do that without switching my whole program to radiobuttons?

Comment: @Melye77: store the actionCommand of the last button pressed in a field, and simply query that field in the menu's code, but it sounds like a duplication of effort. Why not simply do whatever command is desired in the button's ActionListener and do away with any separate menu.   1+. MP: glad you're not posting code that returns from a void method. yikes.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It's still early morning, give me a chance ;)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to present the user with several options, let him choose one of the options, and then have him press a "submit" button to submit that option to the program. If so, then I think that your best bet is to use JRadioButtons, all added to a ButtonGroup -- this allows only one of the radio buttons to be selected at any time, or use a JComboBox. Either way, it would be easy to extract the information regarding which selection the user made. If you use the first option, use of JRadioButtons, ButtonGroup and a "submit" button, you simply get the selected ButtonModel from the ButtonGroup by calling its `getSelection()` method, and then extract the actionCommand String from this model by calling `getActionCommand()`. If you decide on the second option, use of a JComboBox together with a "submit" button, then simply call `getSelectedItem()` on the JComboBox within  your submit button's ActionListener.

Below I show you both options. Note that my submit button doesn't use an ActionListener but rather an AbstractAction, which is kind of like an ActionListener on steroids.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SelectionEg extends JPanel {
    private static final String[] SELECTIONS = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"};
    private ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup(); 
    private JComboBox<String> selectionComboBox = new JComboBox<>(SELECTIONS);

    public SelectionEg() {
        for (String selection : SELECTIONS) {
            JRadioButton radioButton = new JRadioButton(selection);
            radioButton.setActionCommand(selection);
            add(radioButton);
            buttonGroup.add(radioButton);
        }
        add(selectionComboBox);
        add(new JButton(new SubmitAction("Submit")));        
    }

    private class SubmitAction extends AbstractAction {
        public SubmitAction(String name) {
            super(name);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, (int) name.charAt(0));
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            ButtonModel model = buttonGroup.getSelection();
            if (model == null) {
                // nothing selected yet, ignore this
                return;
            }
            String message = "The selected radio button is: " + model.getActionCommand();
            System.out.println(message);

            message = "The selection from the combo box is: " + selectionComboBox.getSelectedItem();
            System.out.println(message);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Selelection Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new SelectionEg());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```